# How to scale 3D object in Xcode using Inspector?

Tags: ios, xcode, 3d, scenekit, blender

I'm trying to scale my 3D object which I've exported from Blender in .dae format (In Xcode -> Inspector). When I've changed the value of the scale parameter, Bounding Box didn't change.

Here is what I've in Xcode.
Before scale changing:
[image]
After scale changing:
[image]

And there is no effect in the simulator too. 
What I am doing wrong? When I've exported my model from Blender, I've set these properties, maybe the issue is with my export:

[image]

I need to be able to resize the object in Xcode to make it bigger or smaller on the actual screen. How to change Bounding Box value here?

Answer (score 0):

After combining a few good answers, I've found a solution:

Blender

1. First of all, I need to group all my objects inside the mouth in one. In Blender, I've selected all objects  which I want to group in `Outliner` (press Shift and select) and I've pressed `Ctrl+J`.
2. Then, I need to check the 3D manipulator position. Go to Editor Mode, select all vertexes with `A`, press `shift+S` and select “cursor to selected”.
3. Switch to Object mode, press `SHIFT+CTRL+ALT+C` and select `Origin to 3D cursor`.

Xcode

4. In Scene Graf press `+` and add (It will add an empty node)
5. Put your objects inside a new node.
6. When you'll change the scale of your objects, the parent's node `Bounding Box` will change and you'll see it properly in the simulator. 
   [image]
   [image]